# Rar only certain extensions?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, rar, winrar

I'm using RAR at cmd

How can I rar only `*.cs` && `*.ashx` ?

I tries with the `@listfiles.lst` file which contains the extensions but it doesn't work. ( it adds all files !)

any help ?

the command is

`rar a @t.lst -t -rr1024 -isnd -m1 -mt5 -r c:\Projects\ES2\`

where t.lst is :

```
*.cs
*.ashx
```

Comment: You can always copy only those files to a separate directory and then rar them as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sourceSyntax: **rar a rarfile file-to-add [file-to-add...]**

```
# rar a source.rar *.cs *.ashx

RAR 3.90 beta 2   Copyright (c) 1993-2009
Alexander Roshal   3 Jun 2009
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help
Evaluation copy. Please register.

Creating archive var-log-cups.rar
Adding    test.cs OK
Adding    test.ashx OK
Done
```

Obligatory scolding: Stop using RAR.  The RAR format is proprietary, and the creators have shown no interest in opening the specifications. There are no compelling reasons to use it over any number of alternatives.

Comment: Hi. I dont understnad why not to use RAR. and if so , what to use ? 7z ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, 7zip is a good alternative, and recommended. It is newer and has better compression and options.  RAR is outdated.

Comment: @jnovack RAR 3.90 is outdated but 4.20 is comparatively new, dated 2012. Being closed-sourced is not a reason to stop using the software, is it? Windows is also closed-sourced.

Answer (score 0):

This compresses only `.exe` and `.msi` files:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "winrarPath=C:\Program Files\WinRAR"  REM Change this path if WinRAR is installed elsewhere

set "extensions=.exe .msi"
set "compressionMethod=-m0"

pushd "%~dp0"

if not exist "%winrarPath%\winrar.exe" (
    echo WinRAR not found in the specified path: "%winrarPath%"
    exit /b
)

for %%E in (%extensions%) do (
    for /r %%F in (*%%E) do (
        "%winrarPath%\winrar.exe" a %compressionMethod% "%%~nF.rar" "%%F"
    )
)

popd

endlocal
```